# Play Framework JSON Mapping of a Case class Map

Tags: json, playframework

I have the following type that I would like to serialize and de-serialize!

```
val myType = Map[Long, MyType]
```

Where that MyType is a trait

```
trait MyType {
  def x: String
  def y: Int
}
```

I then have some implementations of MyType as:

```
  case class A(
    val x: String,
    val y: Int)
    extends MyType

  case class B(
    val x: String,
    val y: Int)
    extends MyType
```

I have written the following JSON formats:

```
  implicit val mapReads: Reads[Map[Long, MyType]] = new Reads[Map[Long, MyType]] {
    def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[Map[Long, MyType]] =
      JsSuccess(jv.as[Map[Long, MyType]].map{case (k, v) =>
        k -> v.asInstanceOf[MyType]
      })
  }

  implicit val mapWrites: Writes[Map[Long, MyType]] = new Writes[Map[Long, MyType]] {
    def writes(map: Map[Long, MyType]): JsValue =
      Json.obj(map.map{case (s, o) =>
        val ret: (String, JsValueWrapper) = s.toString -> Json.toJson(o)
        ret
      }.toSeq:_*)
  }

  implicit val mapFormat: Format[Map[Long, MyType]] = Format(mapReads, mapWrites)
```

When I run my test that references the JSON formatter above, I get a StackOverflow error in the reads function at this line:

```
JsSuccess(jv.as[Map[Long, MyType]].map{case (k, v) =>
```

I have no clue as to why this happens? Any ideas?

Comment: When you're using `jv.as[Map[Long, MyType]` you're implicitly referring to the very same `Reads` object you're currently constructing, hence the stack overflow.

Comment: Any can you post the actual implementation of `Reads[MyType]` and `Writes[MyType]`, rather than just the `Map[Long, MyType]`?

Comment: In general, the `Reads[MyType]`, should be specific, but the Long map reads can be generic to any type with a `Reads`, see here: https://gist.github.com/mikesname/53563ea6b011a8ce9b85da23a0771b4e